# Зачем нужен оператор default(T)?

Tags: c#, .net

При попытке вернуть из метода `return new Size();` вылетает ошибка `Do not use default value type constructor` и предлагает заменить строку на `return default(Size);`. Как бы не проблема использовать `default(T)`, только хочется понять какая разница?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за класс `Size`, и судя по всему ругается решарпер

Comment: @Grundy, Класс `Size` из `System.Windows`. Решарпер отключил, проблема та же.

Comment: какая версия студии?

Comment: @Grundy, `VS Enterprise 2015 Update3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот связанное обсуждение: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/1482.

Дело в том, что для структур переопределение конструктора по умолчанию на текущий момент не разрешено. У структур всегда есть начальное значение (инициализированное нулями), которое может представлять собой «плохое», неправильное значение. Например, `CancellationToken`: его начальное значение совпадает с `CancellationToken.None`.

Если вы используете синтаксис с `new`, это выглядит так, как будто бы вы создаёте хорошее, пригодное к использованию как и все другие значение. Синтаксис с `default` позволяет подчеркнуть, что это специальное неинициализированное значение.

---

Заметьте, что это не ошибка компиляции, а предупреждение анализатора стилей. Вы вполне можете отключить его в настройках, оно влияет лишь на читаемость кода.

---

Заметьте, что если разрешат конструкторы структур без параметров, отличие между `new T()` и `default(T)` станет более серьёзным: `default(T)` будет означать неинициализированное, прописанное нулями значение, а конструктор сможет выполнить добавочную инициализацию.

Comment: ну или так :-) как-то более целостное объяснение вышло :)

Comment: кстати, раз это правило анализатора, его можно отключить?

Comment: :-D ответил на комментарий, до того как я его отправил :-D

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да, можно отключить. Как раз дописал именно это.

Comment: @Grundy: Телепатия на марше!

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо, буду знать. И получается это не просто предупреждение, т.к. проект не компилируется пока не заменишь строку на `default(T)`.

Comment: @Lightness: Это у вас где-то в настройках указано считать предупреждения анализаторов ошибками. Должно настраиваться.

Comment: @VladD, Да, скорей всего так и есть.

Answer (score 7):

Данный оператор нужен, чтобы [получить значение по умолчанию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)

1. null - для ссылочных типов
2. 0 или структуру, для типов-значений.

В MSVS 2013, все работает без предупреждений.

Судя по всему, в анализаторы кода новых студий [добавили данное правило](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/1482)

В принципе выглядит вполне резонно, учитывая, что у структур не может быть конструктора без параметров.

И так как результат вызовов `default(Size)` и `new Size()` абсолютно одинаковый, вызов `default` может казаться более логичным.

[Из комментария @VladD:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551379/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-defaultt/551384?noredirect=1#comment707750_551384)

> Первичная цель существования `default(T)` — шаблоны. В шаблоне программист не знает, есть ли у `T` значение `null`, и есть ли конструктор без параметров. А вот `default(T)` есть всегда.

Comment: Имеет смысл ещё сказать, что первичная цель существования `default(T)` — шаблоны. В шаблоне программист не знает, есть ли у `T` значение `null`, и есть ли конструктор без параметров. А вот `default(T)` есть всегда.

Comment: @VladD, добавил комментарий в ответ :)